# Fill box dynamically with screen height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a box, which I am trying to size perfectly to fit within the browser viewport **if** the image is not larger then it. So the image would appear to be centered within the window.

Currently I don' think my method of seeking the browser height is working. And for some reason there is a lot of extra space

**[Example](http://www.beeskneesfx.com/viewer.html?src=aHR0cDovL2ZjMDQuZGV2aWFudGFydC5uZXQvZnM3MC9mLzIwMTQvMjc5LzAvYy9kZXN0cm9pZF9ieV9iZnh3YWxrZXItZDgxdHBsbC5wbmc=&t=aHR0cDovL3d3dy5iZWVza25lZXNmeC5jb20vc2hvd3RocmVhZC5waHAvMzQ3LUxBLURlc3Ryb2lk)** *([src](http://beeskneesfx.com/js/bfx.viewer.js))*

**here is where I define the page sizes**

```
if ( style['img-width'] > screenwidth ) {
    style['body-width'] = style['img-width'] + ( style['img-padding'] * 2 );
} else {
    style['body-width'] = screenwidth;
}

style['body-height'] = ( style['img-height'] > screenheight ) ? 
                         ( style['img-height'] + 
                           ( style['img-padding'] * 2 ) + 
                           style['header-height'] 
                         ) : 
                         screenheight;

$('body').css({ 'width': style['body-width']+'px' });

theater.css({
            'width': style['body-width']+'px',
            'height': style['body-height']+'px',
            });

theaterheadcon.css('width', style['body-width']+'px');
theaterheader.css('width', style['body-width']+'px');
```

**How I am defining screen width/height**

```
screenwidth = isNaN(window.outerWidth) ? window.clientWidth : window.outerWidth,
screenheight = isNaN(window.outerHeight) ? window.clientHeight : window.outerHeight;
```

Comment: Did you tried $(window).height() to obtain the window height, then set it into your image height with css method?

Comment: I added how I am obtaining the window height below the code.

Comment: Instead of a JavaScript solution, I'd use min-height: 100vh; unless you absolutely want to support IE8 and lower...

Comment: The problem is the image is floating, and always will be a different height/width, up to 5MP.

Comment: Can you convert this to a background-image?

Comment: Basically the image should take up the whole screen besides the top bar, and if it's smaller, float in the center of the page (similar to Firefox image view)

Comment: I think I'd have issues again with obtaining the correct box size, and not have the right effects on the image (drop shadow)

Comment: A `background-size: cover` would probably take care of both of those issues.

Comment: Still don't understand why go through all the trouble with JavaScript. A nice 100vh solution would look like this: http://jsfiddle.net/8g4dLekf/2/.

Comment: Because of this: http://jsfiddle.net/WASasquatch/8g4dLekf/3/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic of centering items to a content with javascript and css:

```
/*css*/
#myImage
{
    position:absolute;
}
```

And in java:

```
/*javascript*/
var img=$('#myImage');
var winWidth=$(window).width();
var winHeight=$(window).height();

if(img.height()>winHeight)
{
    img.css('height', winHeight + "px");
}
img.css('left',(winWidth/2) + "px");
img.css('top',(winHeight/2) + "px");
img.css('margin-left',(-(img.width()/2)) + "px");
img.css('margin-top',(-(img.height()/2)) + "px");
```

The margin approach guaranties that the image will stay at the center even on page resize

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, though best to follow OP var scope.

Answer (score 0):

I tried here in DIVs in your case code will detect your image size itself

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            var windowheight = $(window).height();
            var windowwidth = $(window).width();
            var boxheight = $('#box').outerHeight();
            var boxwidth = $('#box').outerWidth();
            var imgheight = $('.img').outerHeight();
            var imgwidth = $('.img').outerWidth();
            if(imgheight > boxheight || imgwidth > boxwidth){
            $('#box').css('height', windowheight).css('width', windowwidth);
            $('.img').css('margin-left',((windowwidth - imgwidth)/2)+'px');
             $('.img').css('margin-top',((windowheight - imgheight)/2)+'px');
        }
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/a2ypryzj/1/)
change your img width in css to see the action

if you want your div to not going outside the window after margin the image to center use that code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        var windowheight = $(window).height();
        var windowwidth = $(window).width();
        var boxheight = $('#box').outerHeight();
        var boxwidth = $('#box').outerWidth();
        var imgheight = $('.img').outerHeight();
        var imgwidth = $('.img').outerWidth();
        if(imgheight > boxheight || imgwidth > boxwidth){
        $('#box').css('position','absolute').css('width', 'auto').css('height', 'auto').css('left', '0').css('top', '0').css('right', '0').css('bottom', '0');
        $('.img').css('margin-left',((windowwidth - imgwidth)/2)+'px');
         $('.img').css('margin-top',((windowheight - imgheight)/2)+'px');
    }
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/a2ypryzj/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, though best to follow OP var scope.